# Is it possible to simulate the behaviour of sprintf("%g") using the Rails NumberHelper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printf

`sprintf("%g", [float])` allows me to format a floating point number without specifying precision, such that `10.00` is rendered as `10` and `10.01` is rendered as `10.01`, and so on.  This is neat.

In my application I'm rendering numbers using the Rails NumberHelper methods so that I can take advantage of the localization features, but I can't figure out how to achieve the above functionality through these helpers since they expect an explicit `:precision` option.

Is there a simple way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by adding another method to the `NumberHelper` module as follows:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers #:nodoc:
    module NumberHelper
      # Formats a +number+ such that the the level of precision is determined using the logic of sprintf("%g%"), that
      # is: "Convert a floating point number using exponential form if the exponent is less than -4 or greater than or
      #      equal to the precision, or in d.dddd form otherwise."
      # You can customize the format in the +options+ hash.
      #
      # ==== Options
      # * <tt>:separator</tt>  - Sets the separator between the units (defaults to ".").
      # * <tt>:delimiter</tt>  - Sets the thousands delimiter (defaults to "").
      #
      # ==== Examples
      #  number_with_auto_precision(111.2345)                    # => "111.2345"
      #  number_with_auto_precision(111)                         # => "111"
      #  number_with_auto_precision(1111.2345, :separator => ',', :delimiter => '.')  # "1,111.2345"
      #  number_with_auto_precision(1111, :separator => ',', :delimiter => '.')       # "1,111"
      def number_with_auto_precision(number, *args)
        options = args.extract_options!
        options.symbolize_keys!

        defaults           = I18n.translate(:'number.format', :locale => options[:locale], :raise => true) rescue {}
        separator ||= (options[:separator] || defaults[:separator])
        delimiter ||= (options[:delimiter] || defaults[:delimiter])

        begin
          number_with_delimiter("%g" % number,
            :separator => separator,
            :delimiter => delimiter)
        rescue
          number
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is the specific call to `number_with_delimiter` with the `%g` option which renders the number as described in the code comments above.

This works great for me, but I'd welcome thoughts on this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use Ruby's [Kernel::sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962) with NumberHelper? Recommended usage with [this syntax](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770):  `str % arg`  where `str` is the format string (`%g` in your case):

```
>> "%g" % 10.01
=> "10.01"
>> "%g" % 10
=> "10"
```

Then you can use the NumberHelper to print just the currency symbol:

```
>>  foo = ActionView::Base.new
>>  foo.number_to_currency(0, :format => "%u") + "%g"%10.0 
=> "$10"
```

and define your own convenience method:

```
 def pretty_currency(val) 
    number_to_currency(0, :format => "%u") + "%g"%val
 end

pretty_currency(10.0)  # "$10"
pretty_currency(10.01) # "$10.01"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't achieve what I need.  Specifically, I require the number formatted with different separators and delimiters based on the current locale of the user.  So basically I need to use "%g" inside the NumberHelper method itself, which isn't possible to override.  I will post my workaround as an answer.